# How to use proxy for connection from Cosmos SDK .Net to Azure Cosmos?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

my client is behind a corporate proxy on `http://localhost:9000/`. I've tried to set the Proxy in my .Net Core 5 WebApi App via that code:

```
var client = new CosmosClient(dbConfig.GetValue<string>("Endpoint"), dbConfig.GetValue<string>("Key"), new CosmosClientOptions()
{
    WebProxy = new WebProxy("http://localhost:9000/", true)
});
```

But the connection is not Working. I receive a `Service unavailable`. After closing proxy connection and having direct internet access my .Net backend is working. Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the answer is `Gateway`-mode:

```
var client = new CosmosClient(dbConfig.GetValue<string>("Endpoint"), dbConfig.GetValue<string>("Key"), new CosmosClientOptions()
{
    WebProxy = new WebProxy("http://localhost:9000/", true),
    ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Gateway
});
```

Comment: That's correct. The SDK by default uses [Direct mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-sdk-connection-modes)